# Replicate an Ubuntu server onto another ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, cloning

I am very new to using ubuntu servers and I have two of them. One has everything I need configured properly and working (it runs a nodes app that I developed), the other is a fresh, stronger server I just received. How would I go about copying/replicating the entire server from my first one to my second one? both are running versions 16.04

Comment: swap the hdds between the 2 machines.

Comment: Use clonezilla to make an image of the good OS and clone it onto the new machine.

Comment: I am using Rackspace which means I don't have access to the actually hdds, thanks I'll look into Clonezilla

Comment: I don't think this is a request for learning materials at all.  It does show a lack of effort though and for that I will downvote.  [Are we abusing “Request for learning materials” as a reason to close?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3892/237982)

Comment: .. wr..wrong question @Jesse_b but since you are here, can you clarify "lack of effort" so I can do better in the future?

Comment: @Ricky:  What do you mean wrong question?  -- As for lack of effort.  You should have googled your question first, you will find several applications designed for doing what you need.  Then you should have tried using one or many of them.  Then if you ran into problems you should have asked a question about the specific problem you had.

Comment: For the wrong question, you linked to a post that has (from what I can tell) no mention of my post. I did, and I have tried several applications, Clonezilla for one wasn't what I was looking for because I wanted a way to do this accessing the cli only. I searched on Unix and Linux for a similar question and none satisfied my request. Should I state this effort in googling in the post in the future? or would that be considered unrelated?

Comment: I linked that meta question because people are trying to close your question as a "request for learning materials" and it is not that.  As for the information it would have helped.  Not a long winded diatribe, but if you have already tried several applications you should mention them and why they didn't work for you so that nobody else wastes their time suggesting them.

Comment: I see, as an amateur I have no confidence in my experimentation of the applications I have tried, my hopes are even if the applications I have tried are mentioned again, it would first tell me I am on the right track in what applications I should try and second the answer would be more than "try this" but also have some description on how to use the said application. Now this IS a request for learning material. Is there any documentation of how to display effort in posts or is this based solely on common sense of the user?

Comment: In the help center you will find a guide on: [How do I ask a good question?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks Jesse you have helped tremendously, I'll delete this post later today.

Comment: @Ricky You will not be able to delete the question without the help of a moderator, as it has an upvoted and accepted answer.

Comment: In this type of situation should I contact a moderator to have this question closed because it was of poor quality? I don't really care about reputation but I do feel like I am now trapped because I cannot close a question I have made yet have people continually come and downvote a post I no longer wish being made public. This is a rather unpleasant situation.

Comment: Look at questions tagged [tag:cloning] here and on [ubuntu.se].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The are two things to consider: The installed packages and the configuration of those.

For the configuration, that's what configuration management systems are for. With just two servers it might look like overkill, but I would recommend it anyway, especially if you see a future with a third/fourth/... server. If you don't want a configuration management system, you'll basically have to copy the configuration manually.

For the installed packages: I don't know if ubuntu has some fancy tools for this, but ubuntu is based on Debian which does:

```
dpkg --get-selections >file
dpkg --set-selections <file
apt-get dselect-upgrade
```

Remember to read the documentation of any command before executing it, I would also recommend looking into the `file`.

Comment: Thank you your answer helped me understand better how to copy configuration of my old server to the new

Comment: This is a 20th century answer, there are better tools nowadays. Use `apt-clone` instead, this preserves far more things. @Ricky